# PHP foreach loop and add values to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array ($array) which is structured like that:

```
[auctions] 
       (         
         [0] 
              ( 

                [item]
                        (
                           [id] => 45422
                        )

                [quantity] => 22
                [buyout] => 40
                [bid] => 25
              )

           [1] 
              ( 
                [item]
                         (
                           [id] => 24555
                         )

                [quantity] => 85
                [buyout] =>120
                [bid] => 58
              )

           [2]
         ....
```

I want to store some of these values in a mysql table. Additionally I want a timestamp and if the `item->id` already exists in my table (as the primary key) the other values should just get updated.

```
[item] -> [id]
[quantity]
[buyout] 
TIMESTAMP
```

I tried it like that:

```
 foreach ($array['auctions'] as $auctiondata) {

 $sql ="INSERT INTO `blackrock` (`item_id`, `actual_prices`, `actual_quantity`, `last_update`) VALUES ('". $auctiondata['item']['id']."', '". $auctiondata['buyout']."', '". $auctiondata['quantity']."', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_id='". $auctiondata['item']['id']."', '". $auctiondata['buyout']."', '". $auctiondata['quantity']."'";

 }
```

Comment: `$auctiondata` is a numeric Array, for starters.

Comment: Yes, but can you explain a bit more what´s the problem with that?

Comment: You can define a variable called `$sql` or any name you want, and it **does not execute the query**. You **must** actually execute it explicitly. Tip: Instead of defining a query variable you may forget to use, *only* supply query arguments *directly* to the functions executing queries.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. So it´s not possible to run the $sql variable in the foreach loop like that?

Comment: Yes, of course it is - you just have to actually _do it_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to google **"php mysql insert"** first
There are some references to you

It is no meaning if you update the id when the key duplicated
I think you can use REPLACE INTO instead of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE if there are no any operation.

**Please note that the old row will be deleted before it make a new row with the same id and the updated data**

In addition,
curly braces serve good substitution for concatenation
PHP is forced to re-concatenate with every '.' operator, slow.

[w3schools.com - PHP MySQL Insert Data](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

[PHP Manual - The mysqli class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual - REPLACE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "ur_db_username", "ur_db_password", "ur_schema");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //
}

foreach ($array['auctions'] as $auctiondata) { {    

    //`actual_prices` = $auctiondata['buyout'] according to your code provided
    //it is no meaning if you update the id when the key duplicated
    //i think you can use REPLACE instead of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

    $sql = "REPLACE INTO `blackrock` 
                    (`item_id`, `actual_prices`, `actual_quantity`, `last_update`) 
                VALUES 
                    ('{$auctiondata['item']['id']}', '{$auctiondata['buyout']}', '{$auctiondata['quantity']}', NOW())";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The above if the code mainly copy from the site I provided
You need to implement the error handling